# About warning: "note: expected 'const int **' but argument is of type 'int **'"

Tags: c

I coding for "pass dynamic 2D to function" with C.

The following code compiles successfully and runs fine.

```
void iter_2d(const int** arr, 
             const size_t row, 
             const size_t column) {
// ..some code
}

int main(){
  const size_t column = 3, row = 4;
  int** arr = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*) * row);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < row; i++)
    arr[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * column);
  // init val for array
  iter_2d(arr,row,column);
  // clear array

}
```

but I get warning:

```
t.c:24:11: warning: passing argument 1 of 'iter_2d' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   iter_2d(arr,row,column);
           ^~~
t.c:4:26: note: expected 'const int **' but argument is of type 'int **'
 void iter_2d(const int** arr,
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
```

I think that function **iter_2d** just iterate value of array which cannot be modify in function **iter_2d**,

so input parameter **arr** should be **const to pointer**.

But compiler show me this warning made me confused.

Comment: Remove all the `const`s.

Comment: Making pointers to pointers is a bad way to make two-dimensional arrays, as it wastes space and time. If you can target only C implementations that support variable length arrays, then simply do `int (*arr)[column] = malloc(row * sizeof *arr);`, and change the function declaration to `void iter_2d(size_t row, size_t column, const int (*arr)[column])`. If you have to target C implementations that might not support variable length arrays, then you can use a one-dimensional array of `int` and write your own indexing arithmetic (flat subscript from two-dimensional `r` and `c` is `r*column + c`).

Comment: Also, computer vendors no longer charge for space characters, so you can change `iter_2d(arr,row,column);` to `iter_2d(arr, row, column);` and make other changes for human readability.

Comment: We need a canonical dupe for this question, it is quite common.

Comment: And unrelated to your question, you might want to take a look at [Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason a conversion from `char **` to `const char **` violates constraints is given in the C 2018 standard in 6.5.16.1 6, example 3. Suppose we have:

```
const char **cpp;
char *p;
const char c = 'A';
```

Next, consider `&p`. This is a `char **`. If we allowed a conversion to `const char **`, then we could assign it to `cpp`:

```
cpp = &p; // Violation of C constraints for assignment.
```

Suppose we did that. Then `cpp` is a `const char **`, so `*cpp` is a `const char *`. That means we can assign to it the address of a `const char`, like this:

```
*cpp = &c;
```

Now `*cpp` is a pointer to `c`. Since `cpp` points to `p`, `*cpp` is `p`, which means that `p` points to `c`. So now we can do this:

```
*p = 0;
```

That changes `c`, but `c` is a `const char`, which we are not supposed to be able to change.

So allowing conversions from `char **` to `const char **` violates the desired behavior for constant objects.

This example uses assignment expressions, but passing arguments to functions is defined to behave like assigning the arguments to the parameters. The constraints are the same.

Comment: I don't believe examples are normative text in ISO standards. The constraint would rather be 6.5.16.1/1, third bullet regarding compatible types.

Comment: @Lundin: This answer is written to explain why the rules are the way they are, not to explain how the code in the question violates the rules.

Answer (score 1):

When passing parameters to a function they are copied "as if by assignment", meaning that the parameter copy follows the same rules as the `=` operator, formally called *simple assignment*. So what your code is actually doing between the lines, is essentially the same as this:

```
int** arr1 = ... ;
const int** arr2 = arr1;
```

And if you try to compile that snippet, you'll get almost the same error message, saying something like "initialization from incompatible type".

---

When doing simple assignment, the rule for copying pointers is (simplified):

- The left operand (of the `=` operator) can have either qualified or unqualified pointer type. Qualified meaning for example `const`.
- Both operands must be pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of a *compatible type.*
- The type pointed to by the left must have at least all the qualifiers of the type pointed to by the right. (Meaning `int x; const int y = x;` is ok but not the other way around.)

---

For the case where you have `int* x; const int* y = x;` the compiler won't complain. `y` is a qualified pointer to int type, `x` is an unqualified pointer to int type. `y` has at least all the qualifiers of `x`. All of the above mentioned rules are fulfilled, so this is fine.

The problem here is how qualifiers behave together with pointer-to-pointer. `const int**` actually means (read it from right to left) "pointer to pointer to const int". It does *not* mean "const pointer to pointer to int".

If we go back to the first example of `const int** arr2 = arr1;`, arr2 is a unqualified pointer to type `const int*`. And arr1 is an unqualified pointer to type `int*`. They are not compatible types - it doesn't matter that `arr2` happens to *point at* a type which is a qualified version of what `arr1` points at. The rules only care about the "outermost" pointer types themselves.

To fix this and maintain "const correctness", we would have to const qualify the pointer-to-pointer itself. That would be `int**const arr`. Again, read right to left: "const pointer to pointer to int".

---

My recommendation would however be to get rid of the pointer to pointer entirely, since your code is needlessly slow because of it. The multiple malloc calls will lead to fragmented allocation and poor data cache utilization. Instead you can use pointer to VLA like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void iter_2d (size_t row, 
              size_t column,
              int arr[row][column]);

int main (void){
  const size_t row = 4;  
  const size_t column = 3;
  int (*arr)[column] = malloc( sizeof(int[row][column]) );

  iter_2d(row, column, arr);

  free(arr);
}
```

This code is much faster, less complex, easier to read.
More info: [Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays).

Comment: Thank you for providing a good coding style for this example.

Comment: But this syntax cannot compile with cl.exe (Microsoft). gcc and clang can be compiled normally.

Comment: @curlywei You will need a standard compliant C compiler which is not older than 20 years. I'm not sure if Microsoft has that.